# How to zoom behaviour in line chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I had developed for the line graph code, but unable to zoom behavior for the given code,how to add for the zoom in line graph,i had tried for the zoom behavior,but unable to show the zoom in the line graph,the given data i had developed.

```
                     function draw(){

                var s1=data.map(function (d,i){return {key:d.key[0],value:d.value}}) 
                  //console.log(s1);
                var margin = {top: 15, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 85},
                  width = 440,height = 450;
                var parseDate = d3.time.format("%y").parse
                var x =  d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
                var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").ticks(7).tickFormat(d3.format("d"));

                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left")

                var area = d3.svg.area()
              .interpolate("cardinal")
              .x(function(d) { return x(d.key); })
              .y0(y(0))
              .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

              var line = d3.svg.line()
                 .x(function(d) { return x(d.key); })
                 .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); })
                 .interpolate("cardinal")

               var div = d3.select("body")
                 .append("div")   
                 .attr("class", "tooltip")               
                 .style("opacity", 0);

               var svg = d3.select("body").select("#lineCharts")
                 .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                 .append("g")
                 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
                 x.domain(d3.extent(s1, function(d) { return d.key; }));
                 y.domain(d3.extent(s1, function(d) { return d.value; }));
               var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
              .on("zoom", drawZoom);
               svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis x-axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").attr("fill","steelblue")
                .call(xAxis);
               svg.append("path")
                .datum(s1)
                .attr("class", "area")
                .attr("d", area);
               svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis y-axis").attr("fill","steelblue").call(yAxis)

               svg.append("path").attr("class", "line").attr("d", line(s1));
               svg.selectAll("dot")
                 .data(data)
                 .enter().append("circle")
                 .style("fill","blue")
                 .attr("r","3.5")
                 .attr("cx",function (d,i){return x(d.key);})
                 .attr("cy",function(d,i){return y(d.value);})
                 .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
                      div.transition()        
                          .duration(200)      
                          .style("opacity", .9);      
                      div .html((d.key) + "<br/>"  + d.value)  
                          .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                          .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-28) + "px");    
                      })                  
                  .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
                      div.transition()        
                          .duration(500)      
                          .style("opacity", 0);   
                  });
         function drawZoom() {
            svg.select("g.x axis x-axis").call(xAxis);
            svg.select("g.y axis y-axis").call(yAxis);
            svg.select("path.area").attr("d", area);
            svg.select("path.line").attr("d", line(s1));
          }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe ?

```
 {//-------------------------zoom
        var minZoom = 0.2,
        maxZoom = 2.5;
        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .on("zoom", redraw)
        .scaleExtent([minZoom, maxZoom])//-call zoom but put scale extent on to limit zoom in/out
        ;
    }

    function redraw() //-redraw
    {
        var trans=d3.event.translate;
        var scale=d3.event.scale; 
        //var newScale = scale/2;
        inner.attr("transform","translate(" + trans + ")" + " scale(" + scale + ")"); //-translates and scales
    }
```

Call that on your background (svg) and use your mouse to pan and zoom :)